# Predicted data not similar with actual data after training model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, forecasting, tensorflow.js

I'm new to machine learning and now working on a project about time series forecasting.I confused why predicted data after training model isn't similar with actual data.

[see the data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnSwO.png)

I'm using tensorflow.js with reactjs,Can anyone help me what wrong with model created? Below is code about that model..

Anyone who help me will appreciated..

```
    ...
    let x = tf.tensor2d(labels,[labels.length,1]);
    let y = tf.tensor2d(inputs,[inputs.length,1]);

    let inputSteps = inputs.length / 3;
    let labelSteps = labels.length / 3;

    let xs = x.reshape([3,inputSteps,1]);
    let ys = y.reshape([3,labelSteps,1]);

    const epochs = 30;
    const window_size = 10;
    const batchSize = 3;
    const shuffle = true;

    const input_layer_neurons = [inputSteps,1];
    
    const rnn_input_shape = input_layer_neurons;
    
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: input_layer_neurons,units:512 }));
    
    let lstm_cells = [];
    
    for(let i=0; i < hiddenLayers; i++){
        lstm_cells.push(tf.layers.lstmCell({ units:20 }));
    }   
    
    model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
        cell: lstm_cells,
        units: 50,
        activation: 'relu',
        inputShape: rnn_input_shape,
        returnSequences: true
    }))
    
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units:1,returnSequences:true }));
    
    model.compile({
        optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.0005),
        loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
        metrics:['mse'],
      });

    const lossError = [],quantityEpochs = [];
    
    await model.fit(xs, ys, {shuffle,batchSize,epochs,callbacks: { 
        onEpochEnd: async (epoch,log) => {
            console.log('loss : ' + log.loss);
            lossError.push(log.loss);
            quantityEpochs.push(epoch); 
        }
    }});

    const outps = model.predict(ys);
    
    ...
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `tensorflow.js` but the idea in deep learning is the same. I mean, your model is at least giving some results, so I don't think there is any problem with it. So, adding more data, more layers and making the model complex will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong here.

[image]

Your model is working just fine. Predicted values will never be the same as actual, unless you overfit the hell out of your model (and then it won't generalize). In any case, your graph shows that the model is learning.

Here is what you can do to get better results -

1. A bit more training can be done with more epochs to reduce the loss further.
2. If the loss doesn't go further down parameters can be added with a few layers, then the model needs more complexity to learn better. Meaning you need more trainable parameters (more layers, larger layers etc)